# What Framework to use in GAE to expose API

Tags: google-app-engine, webservice-client

I have a web server (Python) deployed in GAE (Google AppEngine) and want to expose APIs to be consumed by browser (Javascript) and other web servers.

Web service API, or "Google API" are possible choices. Further questions, for web service API, what web service framework works on GAE for BOTH cases, browser (Javascript) and Server client (Python).

If using "Google API", what I should use? For my limited understanding, Goodle API is API to expose already existed Google service. If I deployed my web server into GAE, how to expose my API with "google cloud service"?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/), part of the GAE suite, which provides a framework dedicated to setting up API end points. It allows you to develop the API in both Python and Java and provides libraries for JavaScript, Android, iOS and [Python clients](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/access_from_python).

With regard to Google APIs, I also understand that to be consuming existing Google services that you can access through an API (e.g. Youtube, Maps, etc.)

Comment: So, my GAE API implemented with 3rd party web service framework is not called Google API. my GAE API implemented with Google Cloud Endpoints is called Google API, as it can be accessed through Google API client. This is really confusing. It seems Google API refers to already implemented/deployed by Google. May be, it also refer to GAE API implemented with Google cloud service framework. Thank you for your answer.